# MySQL triger to set foreign key to null

Tags: mysql, triggers

I have table named Webpage_Categories (MySQL)

```
Webpage_Categories
-----------------
webpage_catgegory_id | parent_id | name
```

where parent_id field is foreign key, which references the webpage_category_id field.

Here is the create table statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `webpage_category` (
  `webpage_category_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `parent_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `name_en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail_image` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `thumbnail_image_en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `display_date` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `display_thumbnail_image` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `display_short_text` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `display_more_button` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `imported_from_old_site` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `slug` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `slug_en` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `sort_order` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `visible` tinyint(4) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_by` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_from_ip` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted_with_browser` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`webpage_category_id`),
  KEY `Fk_User_WebpageCategory_idx` (`deleted_by`),
  KEY `Fk_Parent_WebpageCategory_idx` (`parent_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `Fk_Parent_WebpageCategory` FOREIGN KEY (`parent_id`) REFERENCES `webpage_category` (`webpage_category_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `Fk_User_WebpageCategory` FOREIGN KEY (`deleted_by`) REFERENCES `user` (`user_id`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb3;
```

Since I use soft delete in PHP, I want when a specific webpage category is deleted all rows that have set that webpage category as parent_id,those parent_id fields should be set to null.

I have the following code:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER _set_webpage_category_foreign_key_to_null
AFTER UPDATE ON webpage_category 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF !(NEW.deleted_at <=> OLD.deleted_at) THEN
  update webpage_category 
  set parent_id = NULL
  WHERE parent_id = NEW.webpage_category_id;
  END IF;
END; //
```

The error that I get in log file is: Can't update table 'webpage_category' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Please add full table definition as text (show create table Webpage_Categories)

Comment: It is not possible in a trigger to change other rows in the same table than the row you just modified. MySQL just can't do it. You could maybe change your datamodel (e.g. do you really need to delete that parent-id? Maybe put the hierarchy in another table?), or update all children in your application when you mark one as deleted (e.g. run 2 queries instead of one).

Comment: @Solarflare I need that parent_id. You can see answer to my similar question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73093343/my-sql-trigger-that-set-foreign-key-to-null

Comment: I didn't mean to say you dont need that parent_id. I meant: do you actually need to set it to null (as you e.g. will lose the information that it was a child of that parent, so your data is in a limbo)? You could e.g. just check if the parent is soft-deleted when you query a child. But this was just one idea - the thing is, you cannot modify other rows in the same table in a trigger. So you will have to find another way, but there is no best or correct other way. Another way is, as I said, to just run 2 queries in your app (e.g. to set null in your app, instead of the trigger).

Comment: Thank you for your clarification. I will give it a go, and if I can not find the solution, then yes, whenever I run the delete query in webpage_category, I will first set those parent_id's field to null. Thanks.